# Search values split by ";" in column 2

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

searching values of column 2 from file1 in column 2 (PDBid-containing numerous values separated by `";"`) of file 2. If found, merge all columns of file 1 and file 2

file1:

```
peptide,PDB_ID
pep1,4BAK
pep1,4BAH
pep1,7R1R
pep1,6R1R
pep1,5R1R
pep1,4R1R
pep1,3R1R
pep1,4CH8
pep1,4CH2
pep1,1DN2
pep1,2NNU
pep1,3DIW
pep1,2G56
pep1,2G54
pep1,1TVB
pep1,2C9F
pep1,1JK8
pep1,2P1L
pep1,4IPZ
pep1,4HPY
pep1,4HPO
pep1,4JJM
```

file2:

```
Uniprotid,PDBid,Genesymbol,entryname
P00452,1QFN,1R1R;1RLR;2R1R;2X0X;2XAK;2XAP;2XAV;2XAW;2XAX;2XAY;2XAZ;2XO4;2XO5;3R1R;3UUS;4ERM;4ERP;4R1R;5R1R;6R1R;7R1R,nrdA dnaF b2234 JW2228,RIR1_ECOLI
P69924,6R1R,nrdB ftsB b2235 JW2229,RIR2_ECOLI
P03120,1BY9;1DTO;1R8P;1ZZF;2NNU;2Q79;3MI7,E2,VE2_HPV16
Q96HN0,2NNU,Homo sapiens (Human),Q96HN0_HUMAN
Q9YIV0,2NNU,E2,Q9YIV0_HPV16
Q9DBG9,3DIW;3DJ1;3DJ3,Tax1bp3,TX1B3_MOUSE
Q6N089,3CFJ;3CFK;4HPY,DKFZp686P15220,Q6N089_HUMAN
Q8N5F4,4HPY,IGL@,Q8N5F4_HUMAN
G9HS63,4HPO;4HPY,env,G9HS63_9HIV1
P00734,3E6P;3EE0;3EGK;3EQ0;3F68;3GIC;3GIS;3HAT;3HKJ;3HTC;3JZ1;3JZ2;3K65;3LDX;3LU9;3NXP;3P17;3P6Z;3P70;3PMH;3PO1;3QDZ;3QGN;3QLP;3QTO;3QTV;3QWC;3QX5;3R3G;3RLW;3RLY;3RM0;3RM2;3RML;3RMM;3RMN;3RMO;3S7H;3S7K;3SHA;3SHC;3SI3;3SI4;3SQE;3SQH;3SV2;3T5F;3TU7;3U69;3U8O;3U8R;3U8T;3U98;3U9A;3UTU;3UWJ;3VXE;3VXF;4AX9;4AYV;4AYY;4AZ2;4BAH;4BAK;4BAM;4BAN;4BAO;4BAQ;4BOH;4CH2;4CH8;4DIH,F2,THRB_HUMAN
```

File2 may contain more than one values listed in File1 as in case of 4BAK and 4 BAH present in last row needs to be taken into consideration and pasted in output file.

sample output file :

```
peptide,PDB_ID,Uniprotid,Genesymbol,entryname
pep1,4BAK,P00734,F2,THRB_HUMAN  
pep1,4BAH,P00734,F2,THRB_HUMAN   
pep1,7R1R,P00452,nrdA dnaF b2234 JW2228,RIR1_ECOLI  
pep1,6R1R,P00452,nrdA dnaF b2234 JW2228,RIR1_ECOLI   
pep1,6R1R,P69924,nrdB ftsB b2235 JW2229,RIR2_ECOLI   
pep1,5R1R,P00452,nrdA dnaF b2234 JW2228,RIR1_ECOLI
```

Comment: This question seems very unclear. I'd advise cleaning it up a bit.

Comment: Can you provide what the expected output of the merge is?

Comment: @BeowulfOF values separated by ; are all in column 2. Column2 of file 1 is to be searched in ; separated values of column2 of file 2. Any suggestion on  how data can be made more consistent?

Comment: ah ok, now i see it. thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question?  Right now, you've just shown your input data and what you want the output to be.  This is helpful, but still doesn't make clear what the problem is with your code, or how we can help you fix it.  (At the moment it seems like the question is simply "will someone write this code for me?" which I'm sure isn't your intention.)

Answer (score 1):

Using csv reader makes parsing of csv files quite simple. I think you may stumble about the second field having more than one value in it - do not try to do things at once. Example is in python3.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

fonereader = csv.reader(open('file1'), delimiter=',')
for row in fonereader:
    d[row[1]].append(row[0])

ftworeader = csv.reader(open('file2'), delimiter=',')
for row in ftworeader:
    for id in row[1].split(';'):
        if id in d:
            d[id].append(row[0])
            d[id].extend(row[2:])

for k in d:
    if len(d[k]) > 2:
        print(d[k][0], k, *d[k][2:])
```

If you first read file1 into a dictionary, adding the first field as value to the key of field2, you can easily merge in the second file. Be aware that the second field of file2 is read as one string, so it must be split and iterated over manually. then, if the ids match, append the first and all other fields to every matching id from file1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{split($2, b, ";"); for(i in b) {a[b[i]]=$1","$3","$4;} next}  {print $0","a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

---

```
awk -F"," '
    NR==FNR{split($2, b, ";");  #in file2
       for(i in b) {            #make a map
         a[b[i]]=$1","$3","$4;
       } 
    next}  
   {print $0","a[$2]}' file2 file1 #in file1, search map and print
```